# Where can I find documentation on writing plugins for the heroku command toolbelt?

Tags: heroku

Is the process of creating a custom command/plugin, such as [pg:transfer](https://github.com/ddollar/heroku-pg-transfer) ( for example ) documented somewhere? I tried searching for this kind of info but I get no relevant results.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately there is not much in the way of docs around that. Your best bet is to review examples and go from there. The key is basically that whatever is in `init.rb` there will be loaded, so you can simply define your additions there (or require the files that define them if it is a larger/more complex plugin). The end result just ends up monkey-patching the toolbelt, so you can also look at [toolbelt commands](https://github.com/heroku/heroku/tree/master/lib/heroku/command) for additional examples. Finally, if you need any external gems you will need to use vendored copies of them. Hope that helps put you on the right track, but let me know if you have further questions.